# Drupal Main menu renders horizontally

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-navigation

I am not sure how this has happened. but wherever I render the block of my main menu, it displays it's links horizontally rather vertically.

The deal is, with each of the themes that I have, the main menu renders itself horizontally, so I am assuming this is not a theme specific issue and more of a general issue.

Anybody with cues on whats happening here and how I can attempt to fix this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because the menu has the `inline` class which is set in `system.menus.css`. The simplest solution would be to add the following to your theme's CSS file:

```
#menu-wrapper-id ul li, #menu-wrapper-id ul.inline li {
  display:block;
}
```

You'll need to substitue `#menu-wrapper-id` for the real ID of the `<div>` that surrounds the main menu.

Comment: adding to the question above...the theme is Bartik and the main-menu is actually disabled since I am not keen on the Bartik menu and would rather have my own main-menu, which I am essentially rendering in the 'featured' region, courtesy which, the main menu renders itself out there

Comment: I think the answer's probably still the same, you should target the `<li>` elements using CSS and set `display:block;` and probably `float:none` as well. Hope that helps